# HiTechnic Color Sensor analog

Tags: ev3, nxt, colour, sensor

HiTechnic sales support said that [HiTechnic color sensor](http://www.hitechnic.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=NCO1038) hasn't been manifactured yet. Currently it's out of stock in HiTechnic shop.

Is there any analog of this sensor except NXT/EV3 color sensors?